# How to check the status of application charge when shop owner click either approve or declined in shopify app?

Tags: shopify

How we can confirm that the recurring application charge is approved or declined?Because it redirects the url with charge_id.  We can get the charge but how can we check whether it is approved or declined?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the charge ID then you can [fetch that charge using the Recurring Application Charge API.](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/recurringapplicationcharge#show)

The response from Shopify will have a `status` property. If the merchant has agreed to your fees then the `status` of the charge will be `accepted`.